# PHP : json array insert into mysql using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

- Below is mysql query which is working perfectly in mysql

---

```
UPDATE call_queue SET missed_interpreter_ids = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(missed_interpreter_ids, '$[20]', CONVERT(2, char)) WHERE id = 58;
```

- Same query i am trying to write in laravel as below

---

```
$data['provider_id']=$provider['id'];
$data['missed_interpreter_ids']=DB::raw("JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(missed_interpreter_ids, '$[20]', CONVERT($interpreter_id, char))");
$call_id=DB::table("xxx")->where('id',$callqueue_id)->update($data);
return $call_id;
```

- But this above laravel query which i wrote is creating

---

```
"message": "Array to string conversion",
"exception": "ErrorException",
"file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel-web\\app\\Provider.php",
"line": 118
```

Comment: you will need to convert array to string first. Use `json_encode($array)`

Comment: @deepesh : thanks for suggestion, can you help me fixing above code which i wrote : UPDATE call_queue SET missed_interpreter_ids = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(missed_interpreter_ids, '$[20]', CONVERT(2, char)) WHERE id = 58;

Comment: i have a loop and values should insert into json one after other

Answer (score 0):

this issue got fixed i just now seen i am passing a array instead of value. Thanks for help